# Create an Indefinite access token for google api with unverified app

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

I have a script that executes daily on a rasberry pi that uses google's apis to work. The problem is that once every few days I get unvalid token grant. Is there any way of solving the issue? And what is the verification of app process like if anybody has done it. Thanks in advance. In case it helps I use the google sheets api in case there is some alternative way to do it.

I have tried to search for solutions online but I can't manage to find a way around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalid grant is one of the most common Oauth errors it means that your token has expired.

Access tokens by default expire after an hour.  If you request offline access you will get an refresh token. Your refresh token can then be used to request a new access token when ever you need.

Refresh tokens are long lived, once you have set your application to production in google cloud console under the oauth consent screen your refresh tokens will be long lived.

While your application is still in testing your refresh tokens will expire after seven days.

If you are only accessing a google sheet account you the developer control. You may want to consider using a service account and make it easer on yourself.

Comment: Created a service account and worked great!

Comment: It really is the best way to go :)